# undefined method `stringify_keys' while using Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, factory-bot, stringify

I have the following block of code in my User_spec.rb:

```
 @user = { username:'newuser',
           email:'new@user.com',
           fname:'new',
           lname:'user',
           password:'userpw',
           password_confirmation:'userpw'}
```

for creating a using using these attributes. However while I moved all these attributes to Factories.rb:

```
require 'factory_girl'

Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.username 'newuser'
  u.email 'new@user.com'
  u.fname 'new'
  u.lname 'user' 
  u.password 'newuserpw'
  u.password_confirmation 'newuserpw'
end
```

and replace the line in user_spec.rb with:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
```

all my tests that related to the User model failed(such as tests for email, password, username etc), all were giving me

> "undefined method `stringify_keys' for…"

the new user object

Comment: did you reload  /exit/reenter your test environment? That has caught me before.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i just tried exit/reenter, but the problem insist. thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and it was because I was passing a FactoryGirl object to the ActiveRecord create/new method (whoops!). It looks like you are doing the same thing here.

The first/top @user you have listed is a **hash of values**, but the second/bottom @user is an **instance of your User ojbect** (built by FactoryGirl on the fly).

If you are calling something like this in your specs:

```
user = User.new(@user)
```

The first (hashed) version of @user will work, but the second (objectified) version **will not** work (and throw you the 'stringify_keys' error). To use the second version of @user properly, you should have this in your specs:

```
user = Factory(:user)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

We need to see an example of a failing test to diagnose, but here is one thing that can cause it – sending an object when attributes are required.  I once fixed one of my failing tests by changing:

```
post :create, organization: @organization
```

to

```
post :create, organization: @organization.attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

@rowanu Answered your question, but let me layout my example too for future reference:

What was failing in my case was:

```
@user = User.new user_attr
@user.bookings_build(Booking.new booking_attr)
```

*Note that I am trying to build with a booking instance and not hash of attributes*

The working example:

```
user_attr_hash    = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
booking_attr_hash = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:booking)

@user = User.new user_attr_hash
@user.bookings.build(booking_attr_hash)
```

And in spec/factories/domain_factory.rb I have

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # DEFAULT USER...
    password "123123123"
    email "factory_girl@aaa.aaa"
    # there rest of attributes set...
  end

  factory :booking do
    start_date Date.today
    end_date Date.today+3
    # the rest of attributes
  end
end
```